# Dealloc gives warnings

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, warnings, dealloc, scene

I am practicing making a simple app that switches scenes with a scene controller (state manager) class.

I created my scene:

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    GameMenu *layer = [GameMenu node];

    [scene addChild: layer];

    return scene;
}

-(id)init{
    if ((self = [super init])){
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        gameMenuLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"This is the Main Menu. Click to Continue" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:13];
        gameMenuLabel.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/1.5);
        [self addChild:gameMenuLabel];
    }

    return  self;
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"ccTouchesBegan: called from MainMenu object");
    [[StateManager sharedStateManager] runSceneWithID:kGamePlay];

}

-(void)dealloc{
    [gameMenuLabel release];
    gameMenuLabel = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

But I keep getting this warning: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1885149/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-06%20at%205.23.43%20PM.png (probably not much help, but figured I would link the screenshot.

I think it has something to do with the dealloc. If I comment out the dealloc in my scene, I do not get this warning. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

This is my statemanager's method for switching scenes:

```
-(void)runSceneWithID:(SceneTypes)sceneID {
    SceneTypes oldScene = currentScene;
    currentScene = sceneID;
    id sceneToRun = nil;
    switch (sceneID) {
        case kSplashScene:
            sceneToRun = [SplashScene node];
            break;

        case kGameMenu:
            sceneToRun = [GameMenu node];
            break;
        case kGamePlay:
            sceneToRun = [GamePlay node];
            break;
        case kGameOver:
            sceneToRun = [GameOver node];
            break;

        default:
            CCLOG(@"Unknown ID, cannot switch scenes");
            return;
            break;
    }
    if (sceneToRun == nil) {
        // Revert back, since no new scene was found
        currentScene = oldScene;
        return;
    }    
    if ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] == nil) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:sceneToRun];
    } else {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:sceneToRun];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add your warning to your post in text format so that it becomes searchable.

Comment: The code in your screenshot is completely different to the code in your question.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a breakpoint or a crash, not a "warning"

Answer (score 1):

You should give a retain property to gameMenuLabel like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLabelTTF* gameMenuLabel; //in .h file
```

And write this....

```
    self.gameMenuLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"This is the Main Menu. Click to Continue" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:13];
```

instead of this...

```
    gameMenuLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"This is the Main Menu. Click to Continue" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:13];
```

The problem is that you are giving an autoreleased object to gameMenuLabel and then releasing again that object in the dealloc section. Hence, the crash.

Comment: Switch to ARC if possible. Xcode can even do this for you. Look under Edit > Refactor